# Android - Data from multiple sources

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm using retrofit, rxjava and realm to build an application. This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Load data from local DB and at same time issue network request
2. First time display a loader only
3. If data is already there in DB display it and show small loader on somewhere
4. When network results are ready update the list and also save the results to disk
5. If network results failed then display a message to use saying that data could be outdated.

I know how to use realm, retrofit properly but its the rxjava part that's confusing. Is there an easy way to do this with rxjava?

This is how the current codebase looks like:

**CategoryRepository.java**

```
public Observable<List<Category>> getCategories() {
    return getCategoriesFromNetwork()
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .doOnNext(this::saveCategoriesToDisk)
            .publish(nwResponse -> Observable.merge(nwResponse, getCategoriesFromDisk().takeUntil(nwResponse)));

}



private Observable<List<Category>> getCategoriesFromNetwork() {
        return service.getCategories()
                .map(categoryListResponse -> categoryListResponse.getData());
}


private Observable<List<Category>> getCategoriesFromDisk() {
        return Observable.just(realm.copyFromRealm(
                    realm.where(Category.class).findAll()
                ));
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
categoryRepository.getCategories()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(categories -> {
                    //Do UI stuff
                }, throwable -> {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To call both functions at the same time you can use the `Zip` operator or the `combineLatest` operator. They are essentially the same, I think the difference is for zip to continue you need two new observables and for combine latest you just need one new observable for it to continue to the lambda.

Do something list this:

```
public Observable<List<Category>> getCategories() {
return Observable.combineLatest(getCategoriesFromNetwork(), getCategoriesFromDisk(), (categoriesFromNet, categoriesFromDisk) -> {
    categoriesFromNet.addAll(categoriesFromDisk);
    return categoriesFromNet;
}) // now you have a complete list of your categories to do with what you want
```

Comment: How do I know that the network is still loading? I would like to display a loader AFTER I have loaded the list from the disk.